# Java hadoop wrong value class: class RatioCount$WritableArray is not class org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to learn hadoop. I have a text file where each line contain one traffic flow. Information is separated with commas. I want my map function to output a string which I build to identify one flow, something like this: "123.124.32.6 14.23.64.21 80 tcp" as a key and value some double (one number). I want my reduce function to output the same string as a key and as a value to take all values from all similar keys and to put them into an array. So I want something like this: 
"123.124.32.6 14.23.64.21 80 tcp": [0.3 -0.1 1 -1 0.5]
as my final output.
When I run it I get an error:

> Error: java.io.IOException: wrong value class: class
>   RatioCount$WritableArray is not class
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable

Could you please point out my mistake and how to fix it?

Here is my code:

```
public class RatioCount {


public static class WritableArray extends ArrayWritable {

    public WritableArray(Class<? extends Writable> valueClass, Writable[] values) {
        super(valueClass, values);
    }
    public WritableArray(Class<? extends Writable> valueClass) {
        super(valueClass);
    }

    @Override
    public DoubleWritable[] get() {
        return (DoubleWritable[]) super.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput arg0) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("write method called");
        super.write(arg0);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(get());
    }

}



public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "ratio count");

    job.setJarByClass(RatioCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(MyReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(WritableArray.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}



public static class MyReducer
        extends Reducer<Text, DoubleWritable, Text, WritableArray> {

    private final IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<DoubleWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ArrayList<DoubleWritable> list = new ArrayList<DoubleWritable>();

        for(DoubleWritable value :values){
            list.add(value);
        }
        context.write(key, new WritableArray(DoubleWritable.class, list.toArray(new DoubleWritable[list.size()])));
    }


}




public static class MyMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, DoubleWritable> {

    private final Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        if (value.toString().contains("StartTime")) {
            return;
        }
        DoubleWritable ratio;
StringTokenizer(value.toString(),",");
            String[] tokens = value.toString().split(",");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(tokens[2]);
            sb.append(tokens[3]);
            sb.append(tokens[6]);
            sb.append(tokens[7]);
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
            word.set(sb.toString());  
            double sappbytes = Double.parseDouble(tokens[13]);
            double totbytes = Double.parseDouble(tokens[14]);
            double dappbytes = totbytes - sappbytes;

            ratio = new DoubleWritable((sappbytes - dappbytes) / totbytes);
            context.write(word, ratio);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what dependency versions do you use?

Comment: 2.7.3 . If I understand it correctly, the problem is that the map function output is DoubleWriteable, but the output of the reduce function is WritableArray.

Comment: can you provide a full stacktrace?

Comment: I am afraid I can't. I don't have access to the logs. It's the worst part. But I think I solved it. I made my map function output Text (I transform computed double to Text). My reduce function also outputs Text (I collect all numbers to array and output it as Text).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

`job.setCombinerClass(MyReducer.class);`

A combiner must take in and emit the same types. In your case you have:

`Reducer<Text, DoubleWritable, Text, WritableArray>` which will be outputting an `WritableArray` but the following reduce expects `DoubleWritable`.

You should remove the combiner, or re-write it (as a separate class to your reducer) so that it takes in `Text, DoubleWriteable` and emits the same types.

Comment: Nice. Thank you very much. I will try it.